# Replace object in an Array with only a reference to that object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a reference to a JS object in an array (ex. `var arr = [{hello:"world"}]; var ref = arr[0]`).  I need to replace that object with a new object.  (Actually it is a backup of the object from a prior time, like when the user clicks discard changes).  Now since JS objects are passed by reference, I can't just do `ref = angular.copy(backupObject)`.  The problem with that is illustrated below.

Simple output from console demonstrating the problem.

```
x = {hello:"world"}
  > Object {hello: "world"}
y = x
  > Object {hello: "world"}
y = {goodbye:"world"}
  > Object {goodbye: "world"}
x
  > Object {hello: "world"}
```

Here you can see that setting the second variable to another object does not actually change the first object.  It just makes a new one.

Is there any way I can replace the original object in the array using the variable that is a reference to it?  Of course the obvious answer would be to just change the original array. However, in my code right now, it would be much simpler if I didn't have to track the object and the position.

I guess I could write a loop like this:

```
for(key in ref){
    delete ref[key];
}
for(key in backupObj){
    ref[key] = backupObj[key]
}
```

But i wonder if there is a quicker way.

Comment: with "quicker" you mean faster in performances or best looking?

Comment: I mean best looking.  This way seems round about, kind of like a polyfill.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`angular.copy`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy) like this

```
angular.copy(backupObject, ref);
```

> `angular.copy(source, [destination]);` If a destination is provided, all of its elements (for arrays) or properties (for objects) are deleted and then all elements/properties from the source are copied to it.

Comment: This merges the two, but the new version may have some properties that are not in the backup and need to get deleted.

Comment: But I guess this way does save me from having to do the second for..in loop,

Comment: @user3413723 You're right. I looked into the doc of `angular.copy` and found out that it can copy values to an existing object. I think this is axactly what you're looking for.

Comment: Yep, I just did that and boom, it works!  And it is exactly the type of solution I was looking for.  Thank you!